# Unable to enable SparkR arrow

Tags: r, sparkr, apache-arrow

This is the code that I used to enable Arrow

```
library(SparkR)
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "/home/spark/spark-3.3.2-bin-hadoop3")
install.packages("arrow", repos="https://cloud.r-project.org/")
library(arrow)
library(sparklyr)
sparkR.session(master = "local[*]",
               sparkConfig = list(spark.sql.execution.arrow.sparkr.enabled = "true"))
```

However, even after starting the session with arrow set to "TRUE", when I run the following line of code:

```
sparkR.conf("spark.sql.execution.arrow.sparkR.enabled")
```

I get a huge error message.

```
> 23/03/21 09:41:32 ERROR RBackendHandler: get on 3 failed
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.handleMethodCall(RBackendHandler.scala:164)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.channelRead0(RBackendHandler.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.channelRead0(RBackendHandler.scala:39)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:299)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: spark.sql.execution.arrow.sparkR.enabled
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.noSuchElementExceptionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:1678)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf.$anonfun$getConfString$3(SQLConf.scala:4577)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf.getConfString(SQLConf.scala:4577)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.RuntimeConfig.get(RuntimeConfig.scala:72)
    ... 37 more
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
  Config 'spark.sql.execution.arrow.sparkR.enabled' is not set
23/03/21 11:21:32 WARN RBackendHandler: Ignoring read timeout in RBackendHandler
```